# Android Error Message: LinearLayout syntax error?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

In the following code I am attempting to use a vertical linear layout but within this layour I want to display two images horizontally, I am getting an error message saying theres a problem within the code but I am unsure why?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <linearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="147dp"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image2"
            android:src="@drawable/apple_gray_logo" />
    </linearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make sure `</linearLayout>` is `</LinearLayout>`?

Comment: @rni2013 Replace linearLayout with LinearLayout. It's case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Change the `linearLayout` to `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="147dp"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image2"
            android:src="@drawable/apple_gray_logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is typo in enclosing of LinearLayout.

Use `</LinearLayout>` instead of `</linearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

`linearLayout` should be `LinearLayout`

If the xml layout you provide is complete, you can remove LinearLayout01 as it is useless, simply do this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image2"
        android:src="@drawable/apple_gray_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, I would recommend you consider using dimensions resources as opposed to hardcoded values for `layout_width` and `layout_height` as it should allow your layout to scale better. Create a dimens.xml file in `res/values` and create your dimensions like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="example">150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You will then be able to use them like this :

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/example"
```

Comment: Thanks, so to add further images/buttons etc under this horizontal layout do I add new linear layout? What do u mean by dimension resources?

Comment: See my edited answer for dimensions resources or http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html. If you need things under that horizontal layout, then use what you had, simply replace linearLayout by LinearLayout, then declare your ImageViews/Buttons under LinearLayout01.